# loop inside an array throws Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, typeerror

I am trying to make this simple loot system to work but I keep getting this TypeError and I have tried everything I could think of.

Everything is explained in the code I added below. It was working yesterday but it seems like today is no longer working...

Here is the code in the JS file:

```
console.info("Working!");
var items;
//here I get the json
$.getJSON('js/items.json', function(data) {
    return items = data;
});
//run the function cuz laziness to put it every time in the console
loot();

function loot() {
  //these are the drops from the mob
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  //define a random number to see what loot it drops
  let rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var loot;
  //if the chance is between 1 and 5(including them) do that
  if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 5) {
    var legends = [];
    //here I loop inside the ids constant to see what items are legendary and if they are push them to the legends array
    for (var id in ids) {
      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM I get Uncaught TypeError here and I have tried everything
      if (items[ids[id]].rarity == "Legendary") {
        legends.push(ids[id]);
      };
    };
    console.log(`legends: ${legends}`);
    //then I random the items inside legends array to get the loot
    loot = legends[Math.floor(Math.random() * legends.length)];
  };
  console.warn(`You looted a ${items[loot].name} | ${items[loot].rarity}`);
};
```

and here is the JSON file:

```
{
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sword of Heaven",
    "rarity": "Legendary"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Wooden Sword",
    "rarity": "Common"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Glass of the Gods",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Minor HP Potion",
    "rarity": "Common"
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "The Enchiridion!",
    "rarity": "Legendary"
  },
  "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Major MP Potion",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  },
  "7": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Helm of the Forsaken",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  }
}
```

Comment: Did you check that items is not undefined?

Comment: it is, I checked in the console. I even tried changing it to `items[String(ids[id])]` but nothing.

Comment: Could you provide a fiddle for debugging?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to move your `loot` function into asynchronous `getJson`'s callback:

```
console.info("Working!");
var items;
//here I get the json
$.getJSON('js/items.json', function(data) {
    items = data;
    //run the function cuz laziness to put it every time in the console
    loot();
});
```

if you run it outside of this callback, `items` variable is not populated yet

if you want to use as function, move AJAX call into `loot` function, store result and make sure to run it only once:

```
function lootRun(refresh) {
  // use self in order to reach it from anonymous callback
  var self = this; 
  if (!self.items || refresh) {
    $.getJSON('js/items.json', function(data) {
      // kind of inner functional cache
      self.items = data; 
      loot(self.items);
    });
  }
  else {
    loot(self.items);
  }
}

function loot(items) {
  //these are the drops from the mob
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  //define a random number to see what loot it drops
  let rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var loot;
  //if the chance is between 1 and 5(including them) do that
  if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 5) {
    var legends = [];
    //here I loop inside the ids constant to see what items are legendary and if they are push them to the legends array
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM I get Uncaught TypeError here and I have tried everything
      if (items[id].rarity == "Legendary") {
        legends.push(id);
      };
    });

    console.log(`legends: ${legends}`);
    //then I random the items inside legends array to get the loot
    loot = legends[Math.floor(Math.random() * legends.length)];
    console.warn(`You looted a ${items[loot].name} |     ${items[loot].rarity}`);
  };
};
```

now you can run your main `loot` function via `lootRun`, pass `true` to `lootRun`, if you want to refresh data from server

Comment: it works now but how can I make it so I don't have to put it inside the callback? because I want to use the function every time I run the function.

Comment: @FINDarkside, this is not correct, since `var id in ids` will return only available within `ids` array keys, in our example: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 and 6

Comment: Hi @Mr.Swaggalicious: Instead you can use promises . Based on the success promise you can take the decision of triggering loot(); functionality.

Comment: @ValiShah I will look into promises. thanks for suggestion :')

Comment: @Mr.Swaggalicious, I updated my unswer, so you can call it as function. using `lootRun()` function. Pass `true` to `lootRun`, if you want to refresh data from server

Answer (score 1):

A few things to note - `getJson` is asynchronous, so items may be undefined. Move it into the getJson callback. Also, you're trying to get the name of an item that's undefined. You need to move the last console.log statement into the if statement so that you aren't using `loot` (which is undefined) to index the array.

```js
var data = {
  "1": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Sword of Heaven",
    "rarity": "Legendary"
  },
  "2": {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Wooden Sword",
    "rarity": "Common"
  },
  "3": {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Glass of the Gods",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  },
  "4": {
    "id": 4,
    "name": "Minor HP Potion",
    "rarity": "Common"
  },
  "5": {
    "id": 5,
    "name": "The Enchiridion!",
    "rarity": "Legendary"
  },
  "6": {
    "id": 6,
    "name": "Major MP Potion",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  },
  "7": {
    "id": 7,
    "name": "Helm of the Forsaken",
    "rarity": "Rare"
  }
};

// here I get the json
$.getJSON('js/items.json', function(data) {
  loot(data);
});

function loot(items) {
  //these are the drops from the mob
  const ids = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
  //define a random number to see what loot it drops
  let rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
  var loot;
  //if the chance is between 1 and 5(including them) do that
  if (rand >= 1 && rand <= 5) {
    var legends = [];
    //here I loop inside the ids constant to see what items are legendary and if they are push them to the legends array
    ids.forEach(function(id) {
      //HERE IS THE PROBLEM I get Uncaught TypeError here and I have tried everything
      if (items[id].rarity == "Legendary") {
        legends.push(id);
      };
    });

    console.log(`legends: ${legends}`);
    //then I random the items inside legends array to get the loot
    loot = legends[Math.floor(Math.random() * legends.length)];
    console.warn(`You looted a ${items[loot].name} | ${items[loot].rarity}`);
  };
};
```